# strange gray area at bottom of tableview controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I can not understand why this tableview has gray area at the bottom of tableview.

[image]

I only embedded table view controller into navigation controller and I add a tab bar item.

If I remove navigation controller, that area will go away.

Comment: what is the size of tableview in respect of superview?

Comment: I am sorry. my mistake. I don't use uitableview. I use tableviewcontroller

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible causes here. Either 1) You do not have enough constraints to pin each edge of the tableview to the superview or 2) the table footer view is being displayed in that place, in which case set the `tableview.tableFooterView = UIView()` and implement `heightForFooterInSection` to return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the constraints? The IB sometimes shows a "filling" TableView in edit mode, but at runtime there are borders because the tableview is not being resized.

EDIT:
i think the problem is that you added buttons (?) to a "ready-out-of-the-box" TableViewController. I think it would be better to use a ViewController and add a TableView and the Buttons manually.